# Error with make and sudo make install command in terminal

Tags: compiling

I am running BackBox Linux version 4.6.

Trying to install GdMap version 0.8.1.

I've entered:

```
./configure
```

and then:

```
make
```

and this is what I got:

```
make all-recursive make1: Entering directory /home/wh1t3ni9ht/Desktop/New Folder/gdmap-0.8.1'
Making all in src
make[2]: Entering directory/home/wh1t3ni9ht/Desktop/New Folder/gdmap-0.8.1/src' gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I.. -DGDMAP_LOCALE_DIR=\""/usr/local/share/locale"\" -DPACKAGE_DATA_DIR=\""/usr/local/share/gdmap"\" -pthread -I/usr/include/gtk-2.0 -I/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/gtk-2.0/include -I/usr/include/atk-1.0 -I/usr/include/cairo -I/usr/include/gdk-pixbuf-2.0 -I/usr/include/pango-1.0 -I/usr/include/gio-unix-2.0/ -I/usr/include/freetype2 -I/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/glib-2.0/include -I/usr/include/pixman-1 -I/usr/include/libpng12 -I/usr/include/harfbuzz -DGTK_DISABLE_DEPRECATED -I/usr/include/libxml2 -g -O2 -W -Wall -D_GNU_SOURCE -Wno-pointer-sign -MT gdmap-gui_support.o -MD -MP -MF .deps/gdmap-gui_support.Tpo -c -o gdmap-gui_support.o test -f 'gui_support.c' || echo './'gui_support.c gui_support.c: In function ‘on_ebox_enter’: gui_support.c:88:3: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘GTK_WIDGET_SENSITIVE’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration] if (GTK_WIDGET_SENSITIVE(label)) { ^ gui_support.c: In function ‘ui_create_event_label’: gui_support.c:167:3: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘GTK_OBJECT_FLAGS’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration] GTK_WIDGET_SET_FLAGS(ebox, GTK_CAN_FOCUS); ^ In file included from /usr/include/gtk-2.0/gtk/gtkcontainer.h:35:0, from /usr/include/gtk-2.0/gtk/gtkbin.h:35, from /usr/include/gtk-2.0/gtk/gtkwindow.h:36, from /usr/include/gtk-2.0/gtk/gtkdialog.h:35, from /usr/include/gtk-2.0/gtk/gtkaboutdialog.h:32, from /usr/include/gtk-2.0/gtk/gtk.h:33, from gui_support.c:10: /usr/include/gtk-2.0/gtk/gtkwidget.h:459:80: error: lvalue required as left operand of assignment #define GTK_WIDGET_SET_FLAGS(wid,flag) G_STMT_START{ (GTK_WIDGET_FLAGS (wid) |= (flag)); }G_STMT_END ^ gui_support.c:167:3: note: in expansion of macro ‘GTK_WIDGET_SET_FLAGS’ GTK_WIDGET_SET_FLAGS(ebox, GTK_CAN_FOCUS); ^ make[2]: * [gdmap-gui_support.o] Error 1 make[2]: Leaving directory /home/wh1t3ni9ht/Desktop/New Folder/gdmap-0.8.1/src'
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory/home/wh1t3ni9ht/Desktop/New Folder/gdmap-0.8.1' make: * [all] Error 2
```

What should I do?

Comment: first off, it may not be the best idea to store the sources in `New Folder`, as it contains space

Comment: @Vlastimil That should make no difference when building something underneath it.

Comment: @Kusalananda I suppose it should not as you say. I better rephrase that: I would only suggest not to use directory names containing space as this is a bad habit under Linux systems. Nothing more, but nothing less.

Comment: @Vlastimil Sorry to be a bit pedantic, and to further derail from the topic, but it's not a bad habit to use spaces in filenames on Unix. What _is_ a bad habit is not quoting ones variables in shell scripts to be able to deal with such filenames. In this case I think the error comes from using the wrong version of GTK library, compiler or other component of the toolchain (but I don't know which, because the question doesn't specify very many details).

Comment: How did u install GTK, did you compiled it?
If you did then you need to specify a path.
You may try sudo apt-get install libgtk2.0-dev

Comment: @Luka I typed sudo apt-get install gtk2.0 in the terminal

Comment: Did you tried running ./configure again?
Can you paste whole output this time.

Comment: Do you have Synaptic Package manager?
You can install gdmap from there.
Or simply running 

sudo apt-get install gdmap -y

Comment: @Luka I tried sudo apt-get install gdmap -y and it worked thank you very much but can you tell me more about the make command and why it's not working

Comment: @Luka This is the error after i enter ./configure and then make:

Comment: I really can't tell... It should tell you which dependencies are missing ...
There is not reason to use make if the program is available in Ubuntu repository, especially if you are new in linux..
please accept my answer if it worked.
Thank you.

You may want to read this 
https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/install-tarballs/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can install GdMap from Terminal

```
sudo apt-get install gdmap -y
```

`-y` parameter automatically accepts dependencies.

Comment: I have removed the comments since they are no longer relevant. However, please note that constructive criticism is a good thing and both of the comments you flagged were saying something useful.